# Button's background color switches to default color iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, background-color

So, I have a simple view with a label and a button. I choose the initial design for these items in storyboard (let's call it default). A label represents a selected file name whereas the button's design changes accordingly. The initial view with colours chosen in storyboard is: [image]

When I press on the button when the file hasn't been selected yet and Label is nil, everything is okay and the button's color doesn't switch to the default.

Here is how the view looks like when I pressed "Select file" and canceled the DocumentPickerView: [image]

**And here is when the wrong stuff begins.** When I press on "Select file" and cancel the touch, the button's background color switches back to the default one I chose in storyboard, but the title color remains the same. Here is a visual representation:

[image]

Then I press on "Select file" and do actually select a file. My label changes to the file name and the button changes its design according to a selected file. Like so:

[image]

But again, the moment I press on the "Change file" and cancel the touch, the button's background color switches to default. **Even if I don't cancel the touch**, press on "Change file" and do select a file, when the DocumentPickerView is being gone, I see the button's default background color for a second at least. So, as you see, the title color remains the one I made programmatically, but the background still switches.

[image]

Please, see my code:

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var fileNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var selectButton: RoundedButton!
        
    var _fileURL: URL? = nil {
        didSet {
            changeSelectButtonDesign(isFileURLNil: _fileURL == nil)
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func selectButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: String(kUTTypeArchive)], in: .open )
        importMenu.delegate = self
        importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func changeSelectButtonDesign(isFileURLNil: Bool) {
        if isFileURLNil {
            selectButton.setTitle("Select file", for: .normal)
            selectButton.backgroundColor = .blue
            selectButton.setTitleColor(.orange, for: .normal)
            selectButton.highlightedColor = .brown
        } else {
            selectButton.setTitle("Change file", for: .normal)
            selectButton.backgroundColor = .red
            selectButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            selectButton.highlightedColor = .clear
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}


@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension ViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        if let fileURL = urls.first, fileURL.pathExtension == "zip" {
            self._fileURL = fileURL
            self.fileNameLabel.text = _fileURL?.lastPathComponent
        } else {
            _fileURL = nil
            fileNameLabel.text = nil
        }
    }
    
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {}
    
    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
       changeSelectButtonDesign(isFileURLNil: _fileURL == nil)
    }
}
```

What I have tried:
Experimenting with function that changes the design, changing default colours, making different design for .touchCanceled, .touchUpInside.
I have also tried making default colours in `Attributes Inspector`, but the problem remains.

What interesting: I've tried linking .touchDragOutside sent event as well as .touchUpInside and adding a target to a button and a selector. The first one works as I need it to. Although, pressing the button that way is not what I need in my project.
**How can I solve it **WITHOUT** increasing complexity of what I have?** - This is very important because that's a test project and the real project I am working on is more complex.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd guess the issue has to do with you setting title color for state = .normal, but the button may be in status == .selected >> have a look a
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .selected)

Comment: Hi @SteveB! What I am concerned about is the button's background color, not its title. The title actually works as needed.